# How to implement Filtering on YII restful GET api?

Tags: yii2

I am working on Restful APIs of Yii.

My controller name is `ProductsController` and the Model is `Product`.

When I call API like this `GET /products`, I got the listing of all the products.

But, now I want to filter the records inside the listing API.

For Example, I only want those records Which are having a product name as `chairs`.
How to implement this?
How to apply proper filtering on my Rest API. I am new to this. So, I have no idea how to implement this. I also followed their documentation but unable to understand.

May someone please suggest me a good example or a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to have [validation rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#declaring-rules) in your model as usual.

Then it's the controllers job and depending on the chosen implementation I can give you some hints:

---

#### If your `ProductsController` extends `yii\rest\ActiveController`

Basically the easiest way because almost everything is already prepared for you. You just need to provide the `$modelClass` there and tweak `actions()` method a bit.

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();

    $actions['index']['dataFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\data\ActiveDataFilter::class,
        'searchModel' => $this->modelClass,
    ];

    return $actions;
}
```

Here we are modifying the configuration for IndexAction which is by default responsible for `GET /products` request handling. The configuration is defined [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.36/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L75-L79) and we want to just add `dataFilter` key configured to use [ActiveDataFilter](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.36/framework/data/ActiveDataFilter.php) which processes filter query on the searched model which is our `Product`. The other actions are remaining the same.

Now you can use [DataProvider filters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers#filtering-data-providers-using-data-filters) like this (assuming that property storing the product's name is `name`):

- `GET /products?filter[name]=chairs` will return list of all Products where name is `chairs`,
- `GET /products?filter[name][like]=chairs` will return list of all Products where name contains word `chairs`.

---

#### If your `ProductsController` doesn't extend `yii\rest\ActiveController` but you are still using DataProvider to get collection

Hopefully your `ProductsController` extends `yii\rest\Controller` because it will already benefit from serializer and other utilities but it's not required.

The solution is the same as above but now you have to add it by yourself so make sure your controller's action contains something like this:

```
$requestParams = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(); // [1]
if (empty($requestParams)) {
    $requestParams = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParams(); // [2]
}

$dataFilter = new \yii\data\ActiveDataFilter([
    'searchModel' => Product::class // [3]
]);
if ($dataFilter->load($requestParams)) {
    $filter = $dataFilter->build(); // [4]
    if ($filter === false) { // [5]
        return $dataFilter;
    }
}

$query = Product::find();
if (!empty($filter)) {
    $query->andWhere($filter); // [6]
}

return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'params' => $requestParams,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'params' => $requestParams,
    ],
]); // [7]
```

What is going on here (numbers matching the code comments):

1. We are gathering request parameters from the body,
2. If these are empty we take them from the URL,
3. We are preparing ActiveDataFilter as mentioned above with searched model being the `Product`,
4. ActiveDataFilter object is built using the gathered parameters,
5. If the build process returns `false` it means there is an error (usually unsuccessful validation) so we return the object to user to see list of errors,
6. If the filter is not empty we are applying it to the database query for `Product`,
7. Finally we are configuring ActiveDataProvider object to return the filtered (and paginated and sorted if applicable) collection.

Now you can use DataProvider filters just as mentioned above.

---

#### If your `ProductsController` doesn't use DataProvider to get collection

You need to create your custom solution.